# Passing a function down as props

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem with a "Nothing was returned from render" issue when trying to put {} around my functions that are passed down as props. I think perhaps I am putting them in the wrong places.

Where should I be putting the {} on this code?

```
const WhiteAdvantageTags = props => {
  props.whiteAdvantageTags.map(function (name1, index1) {
    return (
      <Typography
        style={{
          lineHeight: '2',
          marginLeft: '0px',
          padding: '0',
        }}
      >
        <Link
          href="#"
          onClick={event => {
            props.popupInstruction(name1, 'White');
          }}
          onMouseOver={event => {
            props.highlightSquares(name1, 'White');
          }}
          onMouseLeave={event =>
            props.board.current.removeMarkers(undefined, undefined)
          }
          variant="body2"
        >
          - {name1}
        </Link>
      </Typography>
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: What makes you think the function props are the problem? Looks to me like the issue is that `WhiteAdvantageTags` doesn't have a `return` statement

Comment: Your `WhiteAdvantageTags` component doesn't seem to return any elements in my eyes. Maybe you want to return the result of your `map()` call?

Comment: Yes, good spot. I was refactoring some jsx and it is my first time doing so. Moving the return statement up one line then returns the entire loop. The code no longer breaks, but it doesn't show the content. It is just blank instead. I read that you have to put functions inside {}, but I am not sure how to do it with the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to use {} braces to wrap your function, you need to make sure to return something from that function explicitly. In this example, the proper way to implement it with braces would be:

```
const WhiteAdvantageTags = props => {
  return props.whiteAdvantageTags.map(function (name1, index1) { // added return statement
    return (
      <Typography
        style={{
          lineHeight: '2',
          marginLeft: '0px',
          padding: '0',
        }}
      >
        <Link
          href="#"
          onClick={event => {
            props.popupInstruction(name1, 'White');
          }}
          onMouseOver={event => {
            props.highlightSquares(name1, 'White');
          }}
          onMouseLeave={event =>
            props.board.current.removeMarkers(undefined, undefined)
          }
          variant="body2"
        >
          - {name1}
        </Link>
      </Typography>
    );
  });
};
```

However, since the function simply returns this value, you could instead simply return it directly:

```
const WhiteAdvantageTags = props => props.whiteAdvantageTags.map(function (name1, index1) {
    return (
      <Typography
        style={{
          lineHeight: '2',
          marginLeft: '0px',
          padding: '0',
        }}
      >
        <Link
          href="#"
          onClick={event => {
            props.popupInstruction(name1, 'White');
          }}
          onMouseOver={event => {
            props.highlightSquares(name1, 'White');
          }}
          onMouseLeave={event =>
            props.board.current.removeMarkers(undefined, undefined)
          }
          variant="body2"
        >
          - {name1}
        </Link>
      </Typography>
    );
  });
```

Comment: Your code worked beautifully. Thanks! I am a bit confused on why two returns are needed in the first example. Is it because a function needs to return something, and so therefore you are returning the return? Would it be cleaner code if I stored the return of the props.whiteAdvantageTags into a local variable and then returned that to the WhiteAdvantageTags function? Is that what the pros would do?

Comment: @Jon The two returns in the first function aren't related. It just happened that your inner function had a map, which needed return on its own. The first implementation is actually bad practice. When all you do in the body of an arrow function is return the value immediately, the right approach is the second one, where you move the return value next to the arrow => (return value) and get rid of the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

First option.

```
const WhiteAdvantageTags = props => {
return (
<>
{
  props.whiteAdvantageTags.map(function (name1, index1) {
  ...
  }
}
</>
)
}
```

Second option: I did not try this one recently. You can check if it works.

```
const WhiteAdvantageTags = props => (
<>
{
... // put the orgin content here
}
</>
)
```

Comment: I moved the return up a line and that allowed the code to run. But it is not showing name1.

Comment: First of all , change this .function (name1, index1) {} to (name1, index1) => {}. And it might be good to share your code via code camp.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

Imagine you have `welcome` text passed through `props`
Your style will look like this

```
const WhiteAdvantageTags = props => <div>{props.welcome}</div>
```

If you want to use `{}`. You will put is inside function brackets.

```
const WhiteAdvantageTags = ({welcome}) => <div>{welcome}</div>
```

**Complete solution to you problem**

```
const WhiteAdvantageTags = ({whiteAdvantageTags, popupInstruction, highlightSquares, board}) => {
   whiteAdvantageTags.map(function (name1, index1) {
    return (
      <Typography
        style={{
          lineHeight: '2',
          marginLeft: '0px',
          padding: '0',
        }}
      >
        <Link
          href="#"
          onClick={event => {
            popupInstruction(name1, 'White');
          }}
          onMouseOver={event => {
            highlightSquares(name1, 'White');
          }}
          onMouseLeave={event =>
            board.current.removeMarkers(undefined, undefined)
          }
          variant="body2"
        >
          - {name1}
        </Link>
      </Typography>
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: I thought you pass down props and use props.functionName, props.welcome. Or did I get that wrong?

Comment: I showed you how to receive props with `{}`

Comment: Ok, so there is basically 2 ways to do it: props.whatever and {whatever}. I just wanted to clarify that. I had tried your code and got the page to display by moving the return up one line. But the {name1} data still doesn't show on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
const WhiteAdvantageTags = props => (
    <>
        { ...map function...}
    </>
)
```